# What's the difference between cout<<cout and cout<<&cout in c++?

Tags: c++, cout

This might be a beginner question and understanding how cout works is probably key here. If somebody could link to a good explanation, it would be great.
`cout<<cout` and `cout<<&cout` print hex values separated by 4 on a linux x86 machine.

Comment: Here is an example for people. http://ideone.com/0FZXZ

Comment: What actually *is* the question?

Comment: Why are you asking this. The question does not make any sense their is no logic in doing that.

Comment: @Tux-D: 
Why I asked it: I saw this idiom somewhere and it confused me. I understood why cout<<&cout would print the address of the current instance but not what it meant when we print cout<<cout
Regarding the logic in doing that: Left as an exercise for the reader? :P

Comment: @DanielA.White: Nothing there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`cout << cout` is equivalent to `cout << cout.operator void *()`. This is the idiom used before C++11 to determine if an iostream is in a failure state, and is implemented in `std::ios_base`; it usually returns the address of `static_cast<std::ios_base *>(&cout)`.

`cout << &cout` prints out the address of `cout`.

Since `std::ios_base` is a virtual base class of `cout`, it may not necessarily be contiguous with `cout`. That is why it prints a different address.

Answer (score 5):

`cout << cout` is using the built-in conversion to `void*` that exists for boolean test purposes. For some uninteresting reason your implementation uses an address that is 4 bytes into the `std::cout` object. In C++11 this conversion was removed, and this should not compile.

`cout << &cout` is printing the address of the `std::cout` object.

Answer (score 4):

`cout << &cout` is passing `cout` the address of `cout`.

`cout << cout`  is printing the value of implicitly casting `cout` to a `void*` pointer using its `operator void*`.

Comment: I removed the link since I could not find a suitable replacement.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, `cout << cout` uses the `void*` conversion provided for bool testing (`while (some_stream){ ... }`, etc.)

It prints the value &cout + 4 because the conversion is done in the base implementation, and casts to its own type, this is [from libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00961_source.html#l00113):

```
operator void*() const
{ return this->fail() ? 0 : const_cast<basic_ios*>(this); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout<<&cout` is passing the address of `cout` to the stream.