# Does std::cout have a return value?

Tags: c++, return, cout

I am curious if std::cout has a return value, because when I do this:

```
cout << cout << "";
```

some hexa code is printed. What's the meaning of this printed value?

Comment: Though the question itself isn't (quite) an exact duplicate, most of the answers to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7489069/179910) apply here as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the operands of `cout << cout` are user-defined types, the expression is effectively a function call.  The compiler must find the best `operator<<` that matches the operands, which in this case are both of type `std::ostream`.

There are many candidate operator overloads from which to choose, but I'll just describe the one that ends up getting selected, following the usual overload resolution process.

`std::ostream` has a conversion operator that allows conversion to `void*`.  This is used to enable testing the state of the stream as a boolean condition (i.e., it allows `if (cout)` to work).

The right-hand operand expression `cout` is implicitly converted to `void const*` using this conversion operator, then the `operator<<` overload that takes an `ostream&` and a `void const*` is called to write this pointer value.

Note that the actual value resulting from the `ostream` to `void*` conversion is unspecified.  The specification only mandates that if the stream is in a bad state, a null pointer is returned, otherwise a non-null pointer is returned.

---

The `operator<<` overloads for stream insertion do have a return value:  they return the stream that was provided as an operand.  This is what allows chaining of insertion operations (and for input streams, extraction operations using `>>`).

Answer (score 16):

`cout` **does not have a return value**. `cout` is an object of type `ostream`. `operator <<` has a return value, it returns a reference to `cout`.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/ for reference.

The only signature that matches is:

<del>ostream& operator<< (ostream& ( *pf )(ostream&));</del>

<del>so it returns the pointer to the `operator<<` member.</del>

the one in James' answer. :)

Comment: I can't see any way that this code semantically evaluates to "print the address of an `operator<<` function."  It is far more likely that it is evaluated as `(cout << cout) << ""` and the inner call is displaying whatever `void*` that `cout` is converted to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be the address of the ostream object that "" got printed to

Comment: @Luchian beat me to it with a reference