# If condition Checking for Cout

Tags: c++, if-statement, cout

I read this line and I don't understand what it does:

```
if(cout<<X) //What does this mean? 
{
...
}
```

Comment: it does what cout<<x will do, just that if cout<<x fail it doesn't go to if condition which is like negligible. I remember in my childhood we use such syntax to write a code without ending ; ... for fun.

Comment: Check the answer here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987156/does-stdcout-have-a-return-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It writes `X` to cout and checks to see if the stream is still in a good state.  It is the same as

```
cout << X;
if (cout) {
   // ....
}
```

This works because the result of `stream << value` is a reference to the stream.   This is also why you can do things like

```
stream << x << y << z;
```

since it is the same as

```
((stream << x) << y) << z;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the iostream insertion and extraction operators `<<` and `>>` return the object on which they were invoked (i.e. their left-hand argument).  So `if(cout<<X)` first inserts X into the cout stream, then uses that stream as a conditional.  And iostreams, when tested as booleans, report their status: true if OK, false if in an error state.

So the whole thing means "Print X and then run the following code if cout has no error."

Answer (score 1):

Any expression that contains a stream (such as the `ostream` of `cout`, and since `operator<<(ostream &os, ...)` returns an `ostream`, the `cout << X` counts here) will be converted to a boolean expression that is true if the output (or input, in relevant cases) was a "success" (in other words, didn't fail in some way). If `cout` is redirected to a file on a disk that becomes full, for example, it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

The IO library redefines the bitwise `>>`and `<<` operators to do input and output and return itself. So that `if(cout<<X)` means that output `X` to `cout` and then return `cout` for condition check: `if(cout)`, which checks if `cout` is in an error state.