# cout and sizeof are not returning what I expect in C++

Tags: c++, cout

Here is sth I find but I can't understand one address ,when I use "cout<

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char  a[2]={'a','b'};
    char  b[3]="ab";
    cout<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<&b<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl<<cout<<sizeof(b);//the result of this I am puzzled
    return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
0x28ff2e
0x28ff10
2
0x4453c43
```

Comment: Since you seem to be just starting out with C++ programming, I'll mention a style thing: it's easier to read your code if you put spaces around operators, like this `cout << sizeof(a) << endl << cout << sizeof(b);` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0x28ff2e` is an address of `a`
`0x28ff10` is an address of `b`
`2` is the size of `a`
`0x4453c43` is an address of the result of converting `cout` to `void*` followed by `sizeof(b)` (See [Does std::cout have a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987156/does-stdcout-have-a-return-value))

Maybe you did want this instead:

```
cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
cout << sizeof(b) << endl;
```

Or this:

```
cout << sizeof(a) << endl << sizeof(b) << endl;
```

Comment: Or rather, `0x4453c43` is the output from streaming `cout` followed by `sizeof(b)`.

Comment: `sizeof(b)` is 2 and there 3 at the end of the output. This is weird as though the `<<` operator is left-associative

Comment: `sizeof(b) == sizeof(char[3]) == 3`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this line:

```
cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl<<cout<<sizeof(b)
```

You shouldn't use cout second time. When you do, you printf address of it:

```
0x4453c4
```

or rather [Does std::cout have a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987156/does-stdcout-have-a-return-value)

and then you print size of b, is the 3 on the end of this 0x4453c43

Rather you should just use this:

```
cout<< sizeof(a) << endl << sizeof(b) << endl;
```

Comment: It's not (necessarily) the address of `cout`. That's `&cout`. Instead, it's `cout` converted to a `void *` via the conversion operator.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the address of cout ;)

```
cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl<<cout<<sizeof(b)
```

Comment: The address of `cout` is `&cout`, not `cout`. The reason this works is that `cout` can be converted to a `void *`.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I didn't notice this.

Comment: @chris Implementations typically like to return `this` cast to `void*`, so afterall, it *is* the address of `cout` :)

Comment: @jrok, Yeah, I added "not necessarily" to my other comment since implementations like to do that for `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're streaming the `cout` object to itself, so it prints whatever the `cout` can be converted to that `operator<<` if overloaded for - which happens to be `void*` (before C++11, which you evidently aren't using).

Either break `cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl<<cout<<sizeof(b);` into two lines with a semicolon after `endl`, or remove the second `cout`.  You should put in a final `endl` or `'\n'` too... on some systems you won't be able to read the output otherwise (as the shell prompt will return to the left-of-screen then overwrite it).

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want this bit:

```
cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl<<cout<<sizeof(b);
                     ^^^^^^
```

Older implementations of streams had an `operator void*()`, to allow constructs like `if (cout)` without allowing implicit conversions to `bool` and other numeric types; you are seeing the result of that, concatenated with the final value. A C++11 implementation should have an `explicit operator bool()` insead, and so should cause a compile error here.

Removing that gives something like:

```
0x28ff2e
0x28ff10
2
3
```

as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

*"the result of this I am puzzled"*

```
cout< < sizeof(a)< <endl << cout <<sizeof(b);
                            ^^^ The "puzzling" address comes from this
```

Remove it and [see](http://ideone.com/eCSirT) the result

`cout` output to standard output is implementation defined

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray `cout` there. Note that you're effectively printing `cout` into `cout` here:

```
cout << ... << cout << sizeof(b);
```

`cout` needs some form of conversion to boolean. Before C++11, this was provided by a conversion to `void*`; this happens in your case, as the only way `cout` can be converted to something streamable. Note that there's an extra `3` after 6 hexa digits of the pointer - that's the `3` produced by `sizeof(b)`