# If you have two consecutive cout statements, and end the first with << and no semi-colon, it still compiles on Mac. Why?

Tags: c++, macos

Here's an example:

```
cout<<"Hello There "<<
cout<<"How are you?"<<endl;
```

Should not compile with gcc but does on Mac.  What's even stranger is that if you removed the last << on the first line, the compiler does pick up on the problem of the lack of a semi-colon.

If you add a line of code in between those above lines, be it a declaration, assignment, if, or loop, then it will not compile.

Program runs normally with the error not picked up.  If I went to Linux, it doesn't compile.

If you invoke a particular version of C++ on the command-line, then it *does* pick up that there is an error.

Could the issue be related to the MacOS' use of clang?

I'm trying to understand what the difference would be on a Mac/MacOS between the following two command-line invocations:

g++ -o derp derp.cpp - compiles, then when I run it, it does its thing correctly.
g++ -std=c++20 -o derp derp.cpp - will not compile

Comment: `cout<<"Hello There "<<xxx<<"How are you?"<<endl;` usually compiles, that's normal.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987156/does-stdcout-have-a-return-value#:~:text=cout%20does%20not%20have%20a,an%20object%20of%20type%20ostream%20.).  Essentially, your example is the one-line example given by @YvesDaoust

Comment: In clicking the link that took me to another link, it says that cout<<cout was acceptable up until C++ 2011.  It should be a compilation error with later versions.  Why does this not occur with at least on MacOS, unless you specify a version?  Is clang going off an old version that makes this possible?

Comment: Clang defaults to c++03, I'm guessing that's what you're using

Comment: @baseballphd420 Think about what you wrote: *"[X] was acceptable up until C++ 2011. It should be a compilation error with later versions."* -- In other words, if the code compiles, then the version is before C++11 -- *"Why does this not occur with at least on MacOS, unless you specify a version?"* -- In other words (dropping the question), if you do not specify a version, then the code compiles. Combine these implications: if you do not specify a version, then the version is before C++11.