# Using cout inside an FOR loop

Tags: c++

I tried testing the following code and found that the loop is never executed :

```
   int i=0; 
   for(;i++;cout<<i)
   {
          if(i==5) 
                 break; 
   }
```

I read the following post about the value returned by cout from the following post : 
[What's the difference between cout<<cout and cout<<&cout in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489069/whats-the-difference-between-coutcout-and-coutcout-in-c)

But, I am unable to figure out why. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: You've written a highly non-idiomatic loop; what would you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
for (; i++; cout << i)
```

At the 1st loop, `i++` is evaluated as 0 before increment happens and thus terminates the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The first time the loop exit condition (`i++`) is checked, `i`'s value is 0 (i.e. false). Hence it never enters the loop.

`i++` is post increment. So `i` becomes 1 but the value which is checked in the loop exit condition is the value before increment - i.e. 0.